# SQL nested select statement and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get data from 3 tables.
Table one

```
Itemid 
1
2
3
```

Table two

```
Linkid linkname strlink
2      Google   xxx://www.google.com
```

Table three

```
ItemId LinkId A B C D E
1       2     1 0 0 0 0
1       2     0 1 0 0 0
3       2     0 0 0 0 1
```

Out Put should be something like this

```
Itemid LinkA                                      LinkB    LinkC linkD LinkE
1      <a href="xxx://www.google.com">Google</a> samelink
2                                                                      samelink
3
```

I got it working individually

```
SELECT @Names=  COALESCE(@Names + ' ', '') + '<a href='+'"'+strLink+'"'+' ' +'id='+CONVERT(varchar(10),intLinkid)+' '+'target=_blank'+ '>'+strName+'</a>'
FROM Link   WHERE intLinkid in (197,199)
```

but when i combine it to main select statement i got error message Incorrect syntax near '='.
example:
select x,y,z,
(SELECT @Names=  COALESCE(@Names + ' ', '') + ''+strName+''
FROM Link   WHERE intLinkid in (197,199)) AS links

Thanks

Comment: You should fix the data structure.  Everything you do will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

try this

select x,y,z, ( ''+strName+'' from link WHERE intLinkid in (197,199)) AS links from your_table_name

Comment: sub query returns more than one value so i can not write a direct select statement